# Why my variable not working in template file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a template

```
 <tr ng-repeat="emp in legalDocAssetData">
   <td>                              
       <input name="legalAsset_name{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Name"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]" />
   </td>
   <td>          
     <select name="legalAsset_selection{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Selection__c" ng-options="employe.name as employe.name for employe in borrowerDesignationList" ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]"></select>
   </td>
   <td>
       <input name="legalAsset_email{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Email_Address__c"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]"/>
   </td>                            
   <td >
     <div class="buttons" align="center">
       <button class="btn" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" ng-click="editEmployee(editCount)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
     </div>  
   </td>
 </tr>

<tr ng-repeat="emp in achData">
   <td>                              
       <input name="ach_name{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Name"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]" />
   </td>
   <td>          
     <select name="ach_selection{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Selection__c" ng-options="employe.name as employe.name for employe in achList" ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]"></select>
   </td>
   <td>
       <input name="ach_email{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.Email_Address__c"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount++]"/>
   </td>                            
   <td >
     <div class="buttons" align="center">
       <button class="btn" ng-disabled="isReadOnly" ng-click="editEmployee(editCount)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
     </div>  
   </td>
 </tr>
```

And, in controller, I have a variable

```
$scope.editCount=0
```

My template is not loading and gives an error

> angular.min.js:103 Error: [$parse:syntax]

What is the issue here?

Comment: `enabledEdit` is an array or is a function?

Comment: I think this `ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[{{editCount++}}]"` should be: `ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[editCount+1]"`

Comment: Make use of $index itself. So, !enabledEdit[$index+1]

Comment: `enabledEdit` is an array

Comment: @quirimmo yes, but at the same time I want to increase the variable `editCount`. How can I do that ?

Comment: Perfect, then the previous comments are correct answer

Comment: @quirimmo, edited my question to show what I trying to do. Actually there are many arrays in which I want to loop through.

Comment: See [AngularJS Error Reference - $parse Syntax](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.1/docs/error/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=editCount%2B%2B&p4=editCount%2B%2B)